# Radio Button Vertical Renderer

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to develop a Survey app and I found this example about how to render radio buttons horizontally. But, I would like to transform this in a "vertical render". But this is already using \n which means a new line for each new radio button right? How should I transform it in vertical radio buttons?

```
class HorizontalRadioRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
    def render(self):
        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s\n' % w for w in self]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is html - `\n` won't translate to a new line. Try using

```
 return mark_safe(u'<br />'.join([u'%s<br />' % w for w in self]))
```